# Theorem on Sum of prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Robin's theorem gives an inequality for the divisor function of a number. Is there an equivalent theorem where we have an inequality for the sum of the prime factors of that number instead of the divisor function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the prime factors of $n$ is bounded above by $n$, and that bound is sharp.

Are you talking about distinct prime divisors? If so, the sum is bounded below by 2, and that bound is also sharp.

Comment: Are there no better bounds than n?

Comment: You tell me --- what is the sum of the prime factors of $n$, if $n$ is prime?

Comment: I was thinking on an upper bound.

Comment: This is an sharp upper bound. A sharp lower bound should be $2\log_2(n)$.

Comment: @Tomas, that's only if your counting prime factors with multiplicity --- the question is not clear on that point --- and, anyway, it would be $3\log_3n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I agree on both objections!